# Express res.sendFile forces download instead of serving of HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having the most bizarre issue with Express's `res.sendFile` function. The following is the code in my `index.js`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var path = __dirname + '/views/index.ejs';
    res.sendFile(path);
});
```

Nothing complicated, but when navigating to localhost the browser downloads the HTML instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to render just use the express utility function

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/index.ejs");
});
```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an `expressRouter`-only thing but I got around this by declaring `get` functions on an `expressRouter`, getting the main app to use this router, and then, most importantly, using `res.render` as opposed to `res.sendFile`.

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render(__dirname + '/views/index.ejs');
});
```

Comment: yup that's perfect when you are using the router explicitly provided by express.